# How to find filenames, sort it alphabetically then only head the first 3 characters?

Tags: find, xargs, head

I want to find all files in the current directory, sort them alphabetically before processing their content to extract the first 3 characters in each of them. Doing so will create a sentence that I can then redirect into another file. Ive try this :

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | xargs head -c 3
```

But I get :

> head: cannot open 'filenamehere' for reading: No such file or
>   directory

for every files that im trying to extract their first 3 characters.
I was being able to do it but without sorting it first.

Comment: Do you want the first three characters of the filename, or the contents of the files?

Comment: The contents of the files, edited it

Comment: why are you using `find` when you only want files in the current directory? Are there explicitly files in subdirectories that you also need to find and sort? How should they be sorted -- by their base filenames or by their whole path?

Comment: how far off is `head -q -c 3 *` ?

Comment: Theyre in a sub directory of the current one, their base filenames should be sorted before extracting the first 3 characters of each files

Comment: Cannot try until tonight, will do.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
**1st**:

```
find -type f -exec grep -I -q . {} \; -exec sh -c 'echo -e "$(basename "$0") {}"' {} \; | sort | cut -d ' ' -f2 |  xargs sed -Ee 's/(^.{3})(.*)/\1/g'
```

`grep -I -q . {} \;` will find all the text files only, not binary files like images,etc.`

**2nd:**

My basic idea was to make a hash function with key equals basename and it's value equals the first 3 characters.

```
#!/bin/bash
touch file_s
echo 'declare -A map' > file_s
find . ! -name file_s ! -name sort_map -type f -exec grep -I -q . {} \; \
-exec sh -c 'i="$(basename "$0")";echo "map["$i"]=$(head -n 1 "$0"|cut -c 
1-3)" >> file_s;' {} \; | sort | while read -r line
do
source file_s
echo -e ${map["$line"]}
done
```

The name of the script where you should write this code is `sort_map` and `file_s` is a temp. file. So you should not include these two files in the find command . `grep -I -q . {} \;` will grep files which are only text, not binary files.

The second `-exec` command is as follows:

`i="$(basename "$0")";` will get the basename and will write into variable i.

`echo "map["$i"]=$(head -n 1 "$0"|cut -c  1-3)" >> file_s;` will write hash function and it's value to temp file `file_s`.

`sort` will sort the file names.

```
while read -r line
do
source file_s
echo -e ${map["$line"]}
done
```

Will read line by line and source the file `file_s`. Then will print the first 3 characters.

---

<s>You can't use head because head prints the content of the file not the file names.</s>

You can use:

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort  | cut -c 1-3
```

Or you can also use `b` option instead of `c` but it will assume that all the characters are of 1 byte.

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort  | cut -b 1-3
```

It will get first three characters.

You can use:

```
find . -type f -exec basename {} \; | sort | sed -Ee 's/(^.{3})(.*)/\1/g'
```

It will sort the files and then will match starting three characters and will only print them.

**Note:** All of these commands will consider space and tab as one character.

Comment: Sorry I may have not been clear about head. I actually want it to output the first 3 characters of the content of every files found who was sorted.

Comment: @WilliamChrétien can you tell about your files. Are all files text files like endign with `.txt`. What if there is a shell script with starting `#!/bin/bash` do you want to print `#!/`?

Comment: Theyre all common names with no extension with their contents being gibberish except the 3 first characters in them. I need to sort them out alphabetically before extracting their first 3 characters in them, doing so will create a sentence that I need to > into a different file once I got it figured out

Comment: @WilliamChrétien have you tried my edited command?

Comment: Im afraid I cannot try this kind of command since I have not learned that yet and I dont fully understand it. My mission say that I should be able to get it done with find, sort and head.

Comment: Excuse me if im behind a little unclear im not native english and I dont know much about bash yet

Comment: @WilliamChrétien Well first take backup and then please tell if it is working or not.

Comment: @WilliamChrétien Because if it is working then this answer can be useful to someone other in the future.

Comment: Will do once I get home, im in class for the day. I will try to edit my main post so that it can be a little clearer

Comment: @WilliamChrétien do you want this for files in current directories, not files in sub-directories.

Comment: Files are in a sub-directory of my current directory, like this : directory -> sub-directory -> everyfiles. I was behind able to do the same result with : find -mindepth 3

Comment: @WilliamChrétien then you should run this script in that subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run `basename` on every file in `find`, that is a massive waste of resources, starting a shell for every file found.

`find` (assuming the GNU version, although other `find` versions may also support this) has a directive `-printf` that takes a format string which tells it how to output information about the file, including size, ownership, permissions, etc.; not just its name.

One of those formats is `%f` which is the filename with any leading directories removed, i.e. exactly what you are using `basename` for. So you can use

```
find -type f -printf '%f\n'
```

You need to add the newline `\n` so that each filename is on each own line.

An additional detail that works in your favour is that you can add a limit on the number of characters to be printed in such a way. If you want at most 3 characters of the filename to be printed, use:

```
find -type f -printf '%.3f\n'
```

Now just add `sort` to the mix:

```
find -type f -printf '%.3f\n' | sort
```

and you have your solution.

EDIT: as it appears that the files need to be sorted, and then the first 3 characters of their contents need to be output, the command becomes:

```
find -type f -printf '%f\t%p\n' | sort | cut -f2  | xargs head -n 1 | cut -c1-3
```

This uses the format string to first show just the base filename, followed by a tab, followed by the complete path. This can be used to easily sort the filenames.

`cut -f2` extracts just the part after the tab.

`xargs head -n 1` gets the first line of each file.

`cut -c1-3` shows the first three characters of each line.

The `head -n 1` part is needed in the pipeline, or else `cut` will show the first 3 characters of every line of each file.

Comment: Great response but sorry I may have not been clear about head. I actually want it to output the first 3 characters of the content of every files found who was sorted

Comment: The edited one seems to be a good solution, will try once I get home

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU head (for `-q`) and the shell's default sorting of wildcard expansions:

```
head -q -c 3 * > /tmp/output
```

Alternatively,

```
for file in *; do dd status=none if="$file" bs=1 count=3; done > /tmp/output
```

If your files are in a single subdirectory (as per [your separate comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/498517/how-to-find-filenames-sort-it-alphabetically-then-only-head-the-first-3-charact/498617#comment917908_498520)), then simply adjust the wildcard:

```
head -q -c 3 /directory/subdirectory/* > /tmp/output
```

and

```
for file in /directory/subdirectory/* # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

So ive finally got it down with my own solution inspired by answers. Ive had to do it in 3 commands rather than 1. I did :

```
mkdir holder
find . -type f -exec mv -t holder {} \;
head -qc 3 ./holder/* > prophetie.txt
```

Which got the whole sentence from left to right just as it needed to be. When I

```
ls -l holder
```

They were all alphabetically in order, didnt even need to sort them when doing so.. I guess the mv command did it ?

Comment: The shell did it when you asked it to expand `./holder/*`

Comment: Ive just retried it and they got sort before the head command. How is that. Edit : Did you mean when I mv them to holder since it expanded it classed them alphabetically ?

Comment: Nope; ls will sort them (unless you tell it otherwise), and so will *

Comment: So the wildcard '*' sorted them before processing head on every files ?

Comment: That's correct. The  bash shell does that, as do most shells. The zsh shell can sort wildcards in additional ways.